# Would this be a Star Wars ship? It's full of greys, has round bits on the sides, and a trap door on top

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I cannot find which set this is.

[image: full of greys, has round bits on the sides, and a trap door on top]

Answer (score 5):

Based on

- Dark Bluish Gray Slope, Curved 4 x 1 x 2/3 Double
- Light Bluish Gray Plate, Modified 6 x 8 Trap Door Frame Horizontal (Long Pin Holders)

It looks like [75152-1 Imperial Assault Hovertank](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75152-1)

[image: 75152-1 Imperial Assault Hovertank]